# choices-js filtering select options that only use numbers and blanks

Tags: javascript, choices.js

I'm tring to enhance the following select field with [choices-js](https://github.com/Choices-js/Choices):

```
<select class="form-select" id="telephone" aria-label="Default select example">
  <option value="0901-68738">0901-68738</option>
  <option value="0904-687 11">0904-687 11</option>
  <option value="0906-68712">0906-68712</option>
</select>
```

The select is initialised with

```
const element = document.querySelector('#telephone');
const choices = new Choices(element);
```

My Problem is using the search does lead to unexpected results.

**A search for "0906" does not hide the options that not have the search term**

[image]

**The same for " 11"**

[image]

**Where "738" correctly works**

[image]

**Question:** Which options are needed to

- respect the search where the value starts with a number like 0906
- respect the search where the value ends with a number and a blank like " 11"
- Hide other options in both cases as they do not inlude the search terms

**Fiddle:** https://codepen.io/t-book/pen/BavdjKO

Comment: In the readme file they indicate that they use 'fuseOptions' for their search, you can see what you can adjust there https://fusejs.io/api/options.html

Answer (score 0):

I read through their [README](https://github.com/Choices-js/Choices/blob/master/README.md) and looked through the code itself but I'm not seeing an option to only return exact but partial matches. It seems the purpose of using this library is to filter choices based on a scoring system. Filtering based on another method might undermine the purpose of its design.

A good alternative that matches your needs would be an input and datalist, like so:

```
<input type="number" list="telephone_list"/>
<datalist id="telephone_list">
    <option value="0901-68738"></option>
    <option value="0904-687 11"></option>
    <option value="0906-68712"></option>
</datalist>
```

Update: Thanks to Crezzur for pointing out Choices-js uses Fuse.js for its search. The threshold property under the fuseOptions property of the Choices initialization method is what you're looking for. A value of 0.1 seems to provide the behavior you're after; see below for the updated Choices call in your Fiddle:

```
const choices = new Choices(element, {
  searchChoices: true,
  valueComparer: (a, b) => value.trim() === b.trim(),
  fuseOptions: {
    threshold: 0.1
  },
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply @Charles The thing is, it is working fine with only strings like alpha, beta and gamma. So I would quess is it either a question of options or it is the way the code compares values and fails with integers or mixed as the one with a blank might be treated as string.